# Undefined offset: 2 while using explode

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, foreach

I have `$product_image='img1.png,img2.png,img3.png'` as a string where I explode `$product_image` and show image as `$pro_img[0], $pro_img[1] and $pro_img[2]`.

I get error

> Message: Undefined offset: 2

if `$pro_img[2]` doesn't find any image.

I want to solve it using `foreach loop` but I don't have any idea how can I use `foreach` to fix this problem?

```
<?php $pro_img = explode(",",$product_image); ?>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
    <div class="pro-large text-center">
      <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/product/<?php echo $pro_img[0]; ?>" style="width: 50%;height: 35%;" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
    <div class="pro-large text-center">
      <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/product/<?php echo $pro_img[1]; ?>" style="width: 50%;height: 35%;" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
    <div class="pro-large text-center">
      <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/product/<?php echo $pro_img[2]; ?>" style="width: 50%;height: 35%;" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<ul class="nav product-img-tab" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">
      <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/product/<?php echo $pro_img[0]; ?>" style="width: 50%;height: 96px;" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">
      <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/product/<?php echo $pro_img[1]; ?>" style="width: 50%;height: 96px;" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">
      <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/product/<?php echo $pro_img[2]; ?>" style="width: 50%;height: 96px;" alt="">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The manual has some examples on how to use [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you have various sections (home/profile/contact), that I assume you always want to display either with or without an image, I suggest using `isset` instead.

Isset simply checks if a key exists in the $pro_img array, and you can use that to decide whether or not to print the image tag:

```
<?php
    $pro_img = explode(",",$product_image);
?>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
        <div class="pro-large text-center">
            <?php if (isset($pro_img[0])) : ?>
                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/product/<?php echo $pro_img[0]; ?>" style="width: 50%;height: 35%;" alt="">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
        <div class="pro-large text-center">
            <?php if (isset($pro_img[1])) : ?>
                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/product/<?php echo $pro_img[1]; ?>" style="width: 50%;height: 35%;" alt="">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
        <div class="pro-large text-center">
            <?php if (isset($pro_img[2])) : ?>
                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/product/<?php echo $pro_img[2]; ?>" style="width: 50%;height: 35%;" alt="">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="nav product-img-tab" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">
            <?php if (isset($pro_img[0])) : ?>
                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/product/<?php echo $pro_img[0]; ?>" style="width: 50%;height: 96px;" alt="">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">
            <?php if (isset($pro_img[1])) : ?>
                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/product/<?php echo $pro_img[1]; ?>" style="width: 50%;height: 96px;" alt="">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">
            <?php if (isset($pro_img[2])) : ?>
                <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/product/<?php echo $pro_img[2]; ?>" style="width: 50%;height: 96px;" alt="">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: $pro_img = explode(",",$product_image); foreach($pro_img as $row){ } I want like this @Stanzi1791